# Insert Thymeleaf HTML with JavaScript jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, thymeleaf

I am trying to insert HTML code with JavaScript, but the Browser does not show Thymeleaf rendered

```
$('<span [[$ th:text#{some.property.key}]]  id="counter" class="UI-modern"> 
   </span>').insertAfter("#article");
```

HTML code

```
<p id="article">Example text</p>
```

The key **some.property.key** is the property. In Thymeleaf it would look like this:

```
<span th:text="#{some.property.key}" id="counter" class="UI-modern">
</span>
```

I would like to write the above code with JavaScript jquery insertAfter() below the  id "article"

Comment: Java =/= JavaScript, so please don't add unrevelant tag ;)

Comment: Oh sorry. For the tag mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intead of trying to use Thymeleaf HTML attributes in JavaScript, you can use [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining) and build your HTML that way.  For example:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  let text = /*[[#{some.property.key}]]*/ "";
  $('<span id="counter" class="UI-modern"></span>').text(text).insertAfter("#article");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks it works!  `let text = /*[[#{some.property.key}]]*/ ;`

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf does not work on .js files
It is not clear why you can't just rebder this element using Thymeleaf like the example you gave. You can give that span an ID and then reference it with JS